# How to edit text saved in CoreData?

Tags: swift, core-data

I added CoreData to my Notes App. It saves data, removes it etc. Now I'm stuck with editing already existing notes.

Well, I was trying to remove previous item and save new, but I now how to do it in tableView, where you can just "notes.remove(at: indexPath.row)" and I have no idea how to do it in another vieController. Also, I was trying to remove object with "filtered" but it didn't work neither

This function loads notes from CoreData:

```
    func getNotes(with request: NSFetchRequest<Note> = Note.fetchRequest()) {

         do {
             notes = try Constants.context.fetch(request)
         } catch {
             print("Loading error \(error)")
         }
           tableView.reloadData()
    }
```

This one saves it:

```
func saveNote() {
            do {
                try Constants.context.save()
            } catch {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
```

And I was trying to add edit Function:

```
    func editNote() {

         let editedNote = Note(context: Constants.context)
         editedNote.text = noteDetailOutlet.text
         dataManager.saveNote()
         navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
         callback?()
    }
```

Here is were i perform segue to vc, that makes changes:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "NoteDetailsViewController") as! NoteDetailsViewController
    let note = notes[indexPath.row]
    vc.passedNote = note.text ?? "Empty note"
    vc.callback = { [weak self] in
        if Constants.context.hasChanges {
            self?.notes.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        }
        self?.getNotes()
    }
```

Constants.context.hasChanges does not work as I thought it would be

Comment: You should update the object you have fetched and save rather than removing it and adding a new object.

Answer (score 0):

Core data objects are in memory graph hence when you edit some property of an object and save the context, the object has been edited.

A good solution to your problem is that you have your objects in core data stack for all your table.
you can edit you object inside other controller and subscribe to contextWillSave notification of your context.
this way when you edit and save one note from other ViewController, the running table notifies and refreshes data.

this is how you subscribe to context will save notification

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(managedObjectContextWillSave), name: Notification.Name.NSManagedObjectContextWillSave, object: Constants.context)
```

and this is how your notified function works

```
@objc
func managedObjectContextWillSave(notification: NSNotification) {
    for object in (notification.object as! NSManagedObjectContext).updatedObjects {
        if let note = object as? Note {
            //Do Something like loading table cell again
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Well, i've tried different ways, but I can't understand how to implement functionality, you've provided. Where should I define managedObjectContextWillSave func? In separated class? But hw would I call cell from there? Where should I call NotificationCenter.default.addObserver? I have 3 ViewControllers. 1 for creating notes (works fine), 1 for editing notes and 1 for viewing them in table. In which one should I edit Core Data?